# How can I work around this mass assignment error? ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, mass-assignment

I'm trying to give a user the ability to create a "Link" relationship between two "Tag" objects.

Tag

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :ref, :location_info
belongs_to :user

has_many :to_links, :foreign_key => 'from_id', :class_name => 'Link' 
has_many :to_tags, :through => :to_links  

has_many :from_links, :foreign_key => 'to_id', :class_name => 'Link' 
has_many :from_tags, :through => :from_links
end
```

Link

```
class Link < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :from_id, :to_id, :value

belongs_to :from_tag, :foreign_key => "from_id", :class_name => "Tag" 
belongs_to :to_tag, :foreign_key => "to_id",   :class_name => "Tag"
end
```

Links Controller

```
class LinksController < ApplicationController

def new
  @user = current_user
  @tags = @user.tags
  @link = Link.new
end

def create

end
```

new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@link) do |f| %>
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

  <%= f.label :from_tag %>
  <%= f.collection_select :from_tag, @tags, :id , :ref %>

  <%= f.label :to_tag %>
  <%= f.collection_select :to_tag, @tags, :id , :ref %>

  <%= f.label :value %>
  <%= f.text_field :value %>

  <%= f.submit "Create", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

I know that generally in the create method you would pass the params[:link] to new and it would recieve these from the form after create is clicked but because I can't mass assign from_tag and to_tag I don't know how to create this link object as you would in the console without mass assignment like this

a = Tag.new | b = Tag.new |
link = Link.new | link.from_tag = a | link.to_tag = b | link.value = 5 | link.save

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201192/ruby-on-rails-modelling-a-directed-graph/15201387?noredirect=1#comment21421327_15201387

Comment: Please post the actual error.

Comment: If you want to do mass assignment you should have like this: `<%= f.collection_select :from_id, @tags, :id , :ref %>` and `<%= f.collection_select :to_id, @tags, :id , :ref %>`. You can't do with relations.

Comment: why if i'm doing it on the console do I specify it using from_tag and to_tag then?, also, if theres a way to avoid mass assignment and to apply the from_tag and to_tag attributes in the def create that would also be helpful

Comment: the error I get is

ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in LinksController#create

Can't mass-assign protected attributes: from_tag, to_tag

Comment: Okay so you don't want to mass-assign or you don't know how? Because as far as I see it, you could just add `from_tag` and `to_tag` to `attr_accessible`

Answer (score 0):

In your link model try to add:
attr_accessible :from_tags_attributes, :to_tags_attributes